# How does divination manifest for spells such as Scrying?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I had an interesting question raised a couple sessions ago, and I haven't been able to find an answer yet.

*Spy's Bauble*, a first-level divination spell from [Ebonclad](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/211634/Ebonclad--A-Thieves-Guild-Setting--Adventures), states:

> **Casting Time:** 1 action
>   **Range:** Touch
>   **Components:** V, S, M (a small bauble used in the spell)
>   **Duration:** Concentration, up to 1 hour
>
> Your touch turns a small bauble – a button, gem, coin, piece of jewelry, or the like – into a scrying sensor. You can see and hear through the bauble as if you were in its location. The spell ends if the bauble is moved more than 100 miles from your location, enters another plane of existence, or is destroyed.

How does the character experience the scrying?

- Seeing only one location at a time, like changing the channel
- Seeing both at the same time, like picture-in-picture
- Seeing the remote location as an overlay, like a HUD
- ???

I went with HUD in the moment, but I'd like a definitive answer, if one exists.

Here's the relevant text from the *Scrying* spell, for maximum clarity and to avoid unofficial spells:

> On a failed save, the spell creates an Invisible sensor within 10 feet of the target. You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there.

Comment: What's the name of this spell, and where did you find it? I don't recognize the spell description...

Comment: @guildsbounty It's called **Spy's Bauble**, and it's a part of the *Ebonclad* setting.  However, the basic **Scrying** spell has the same ambiguity.

Comment: Ebonclad is not a core setting supported by D&D 5th Edition...you're in homebrew territory, so it's possible that the ambiguity is a case of poor spell-writing. If you want a 'best guess' ruling on this spell, then I suppose we can try for it. But if you're looking for something more soundly rooted in the core rules of 5E...consider switching out to using one of the core remote-viewing spells like Scrying or Clairvoiyance

Comment: Added the relevant text from the core **Scrying** spell.

Comment: @NautArch That is the correct source, and it's relevant because *they have the same wording*.  "You can see and hear through the [sensor/bauble] as if you were [there/in its location]."

Comment: @NautArch The original wording of the question implied he was looking across all remote-sensing divination spells, and noting that none of them explain exactly how you're "seeing" or "hearing" through your scrying sensor. Which is something I saw as well on going and reading through them all. Of all of them, only Beast Sense has an implication (but not a clear one) that you can't use your own senses while looking through your remote-sensor. Hence my "do you only mean this one?" clarification. Perhaps that might actually be a good question on its own...

Comment: @guildsbounty Sure, but that info all seems good to include in an answer. Yeah, it can go in the question, but the question is really just how does this work? Once you start comparing it to other effects, it seem slike you're in answer territory.

Comment: @NautArch Added the casting time/etc. to the block.

Comment: Thanks! just want to make sure all of the spell description is included (just to cover answers that aren't sure if they ahve all the info.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Spy's Bauble* has almost the same wording as *[Scrying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying)*, which is that:

> You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there.

This does not specify anything about whether or not you can still perceive your current location, or if you can perceive both at the same time, or can switch your perspective between the two.

However, we can compare it to another game mechanic that allows remote sensing, a [familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar):

> Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own senses.

This spell explicitly clarifies that when you use the ability to perceive through the familiar's senses, you lose the ability to perceive through your own. *Spy's Bauble* and *Scrying* both lack this caveat, so it follows that you still have the ability to perceive your actual location normally at the same time as you can perceive the remote location,  and you don't have to deliberately switch between them.

This makes perfect sense for the *Scrying* spell, because it always uses, as a focus, some sort of appropriate tool such a mirror, font of water, or crystal ball in which the spellcaster presumably can see an image and from it hear sounds - it does not take over their senses in entirety. This kind of scrying is a common fantasy trope. However, it's not explicitly described that way by the spell itself, so it's fine if the DM or table sees that working differently - the RAW don't require the caster to keep or stay anywhere near their focus once they've actually cast the spell.

It seems that *Spy's Bauble* doesn't quite have the strong narrative theming that *Scrying* has, since the spell describes no focus which you would conceivably use to view through the bauble itself. Either way, the rules as written impose no restriction on your ability to perceive both locations simultaneously. Precisely how that might seem to manifest to the caster is up to the DM or the players, in the absence of any guidance in the spell's description.

Comment: Thanks!  I missed that part in the *Scrying* spell, because it's in the components and I was just looking at the text.